# Break Numbers List Into Min and Max Ranges

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Brain is not working today and my google skills are failing me.

I have a column of numbers ranging from 1 - 1000.  I want to dump the min and max values for 100 (or whatever I chose) record ranges into a temp table.  The plan is to use this temp table to process ranges of records (in this example 100 at a time) in a larger table.

Swear I have done this before with a CTE but then I had something to group on.  Here I just want to break up a single list of numbers into ranges of X.

The output from the temp table should look like:

Min  Max
0    99
100  199
200  299
300  399

etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this trick from Stuart Ainsworth:

http://codegumbo.com/index.php/2009/01/25/building-ranges-using-a-dynamically-generated-numbers-table/

Numbers tables are awesome, but he uses a dynamically generated numbers table, which is even awesome...r.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all numbers are present in the source table, you can use a recursive CTE to generate the number ranges:

```
; with  numbers as
        (
        select  0 as a
        ,       99 as b
        union all
        select  a+100
        ,       b+100
        from    numbers
        where   a < 900
        )
select  *
from    numbers
```

If the source table is sparsely populated, you can limit it to numbers that are actually present like:

```
... insert CTE from above here ...
select  min(ot.NumberColumn)
,       max(ot.NumberColumn)
from    numbers
left join
        OtherTable ot
on      ot.NumberColumn between numbers.a and numbers.b
group by
        numbers.a
```

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereI have been having a play with a CTE after you posted this and came up with the following, I would be interested to hear if it works for you at all.

```
DECLARE @segment int = 100
;
WITH _CTE
(rowNum, value)
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col01) -1, col01
    FROM dbo.testTable
)
SELECT rowNum/@segment AS Bucket, MIN(Value) AS MinVal, MAX(Value) AS MaxVal
FROM _CTE
group by rowNum/@segment
ORDER BY Bucket
;
```

col01 in this case is the column that you want the min/max range values from, as is TestTable.